# How to determine HP Smart Array model?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

How to determine HP Smart Array model on HP server? I own HP 350 G6 server.

Really do not know where to look, is there a utility tool that can help me find this information, or is there a sign on the hardware?

Thanks

**Ok, I used Array Configuration Utility and here is what I got**

```
Internal Controller 
Controller Status OK 
Controller Smart Array P410i 
Slot 0 
Controller Serial Number 5001438018BF66A0 
Bus Interface PCI 
Hardware Revision C 
Firmware Version 5.14 
RAID 6 (ADG) Status Disabled 
Number of Ports 2 (Internal only) 
Number of Arrays 1 
Number of Logical Drives 1 
Number of Physical Drives 2 


Caching 
Cache Module Present Yes 
Cache Status OK 
Cache Ratio 25% Read / 75% Write 
Total Cache Memory Available 400 MB 
Total Cache Size 512 MB 
Cache Backup Power Source Batteries 
Battery/Capacitor Pack Count  1 
Battery/Capacitor Status OK 
Enable Write Cache When Battery/Capacitor Not Present or Not Completely Charged Disabled
```

Comment: This link has a download of smart array configuration for Windows 64. https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_ebacd285e9d347549d085afe37

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The controller model for that hardware can be found via the HP QuickSpecs technical specifications page. A quick search for ["ML350 G6 quickspecs"](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ml350%20g6%20quickspecs&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) reveals the quickspecs PDF and HTML pages for your server model.

All variants of the ProLiant ML350 G6 server used HP Smart Array P410 RAID controllers by default.

[image]

Comment: great, helped a lot. I have updated my question, so basically I have P410/512 MB BBWC?

Comment: Could I use Array Configuration Utility to expand array? I believe I can..

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [HP Array Configuration Utility](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/software-management/acumatrix/). It should show you the model of the card installed and the current configuration. If you used the SmartStart CD to do an assisted install of windows, it should have been installed as part of the setup processes. Otherwise, it can be downloaded and installed separately.

You should be able to see the model of the card during the bootup sequence as well.