# How to find a compatible disk for HP server?

Tags: hard-drive, hp, hardware-raid, hp-proliant

How to find a compatible disk for HP server? I own HP ML350 G6 server.

I have found a [spare parts list](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?prodSeriesId=3884315&objectID=c01725643), but since there is no disk of size 300 GB 2.5 10K 6G (originally installed on server) I am confused. There are also spare part numbers which do not really match with any MFG# on the market.

I would need some help with this, since I would like to get a disk that is available on market that is also compatible with ML350G6.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need a disk which would be supported under your HP server's warranty or do you just need a disk which would "work"?

Comment: http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/3981977/mfg_partno/507127-B21

Comment: @syneticon-dj what does it mean "would be supported under your HP server's warranty"?

Comment: You should be able to install just about any 2.5" SAS drive.

Comment: If your server still is under warranty, an HP disk would be covered under the same terms as the system. A third party disk might or might not have its own warranty terms.

Comment: @syneticon-dj I am looking for a HP disk, but it confuses me that the disk of same specs have different part no: 507127-B21, 652564-B21,  507284-001. Should I ignore different ids if the disk specs are according to my needs?

Comment: 507127-B21 and 507284-001 are [***the same part***](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=de&cc=de&taskId=120&prodSeriesId=254961&prodTypeId=329290&objectID=c00305257) - the first is the "option part number" while the second is the "spare part number". The 652564-B21 is enclosed in the ["***SmartDrive Carrier***"](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/GetPDF.aspx%2F4AA3-9827ENW.pdf) and would fit the current G8 server line - you do not want that.

Comment: @syneticon-dj thanks for clearing that up for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

John, you can use the same [HP ProLiant ML350 G6 Quickspecs PDF](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13241_na/13241_na.pdf) that I linked to in your [earlier question](https://serverfault.com/a/542996/13325).

*Here are the 2.5" hard drives (and their respective part numbers) that are compatible with your server.*
[image]

Comment: Great info again. I just checked the sign on disks inside the server and it says part no 507284-001. I don see it in this quickspecs. Does it mean that I could add similar specs disk that is compatible according to quickspecs, but not necessary  507284-001?

Comment: The disks have a "Spare Part Number" on the external label. That's for warranty returns. Cross-reference the number if you want the "Option Part Number", which is what's listed in my answer.

Comment: 507127-B21 is on this list, but If I am unable to get it could I get 652564-B21 or 507284-001 that represent disks with same specs as 507127-B21. Is there a huge catch between different option part numbers?

Comment: Buy what's listed above. I've pointed you directly at the compatible parts and SKU numbers...

Comment: Will do. Last question, I want to build a RAID 1+0. I have 2 orig. installed disks  and want to add 4 more. Is it a problem if 2 disks come with different part number then new 4 disks?

Comment: Get the same disks... *exactly* what's listed above.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an HP server, you need to look up the "QuickSpecs"  document. This is the document that gives you the full compatible parts list for the server. The ML350 does have an extensive list of compatible storage parts, and yours is very likely in there.

The QuickSpec document is the go-to document for HP server to find out what HP branded parts can be used in them.